# R shiny login hack

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Having tried the evaluation of the RStudio Shiny Pro Server I am not super enthused by the login/authentication mechanism as their is no simple mechanism to manage user accounts for clients to access a shiny app.

As such I am attempting to create my own login mechanism within Shiny which for all intents and purposes is working ok, apart from the display of things within the `shinydashboard` framework. Things seem to cut off before all the content is displayed. My login code is a slight ammend to https://gist.github.com/withr/9001831, so thanks a bunch there.

My code:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)

my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "abc"

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "my heading")
sidebar <- uiOutput("sidebarpanel")
body <- uiOutput("body")

login <- box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
             passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
             br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))

mainpage <- "some data"

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { 
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarUserPanel("myuser",subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href="__logout__")),
        selectInput("in_var", "myvar", multiple = FALSE,
                  choices = c("option 1","option 2")),
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart")),
          menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("dollar")),
          menuItem("Item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("credit-card")),
          menuItem("Item 4", tabName = "t_item4", icon = icon("share-alt"))
        ))}
  })

  output$body <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      dashboardBody(mainpage)
    }
    else {
      dashboardBody(login)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I load the app it looks like this:
[image: Initial sceen capture]

If I then resize the screen slightly it fixes itself.[image: Resize screen capture]

Any thoughts on how to avoid the strange initial behaviour would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem can be fixed by putting the `dashboardSidebar` and `dashboardBody` function outside of the `renderUI`, just like:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "my heading")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel"))
body <- dashboardBody( uiOutput("body") )
```

It will create a empty side bar and a body that later you can fill using the `renderUI` function.

Since you have multiple components in "sidebarpanel" you can group then by replacing the `dashboardSidebar` function with a `div` function:

```
      output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
        if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { 
          div(
            sidebarUserPanel("myuser",subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href="__logout__")),
            selectInput("in_var", "myvar", multiple = FALSE,
                      choices = c("option 1","option 2")),
            sidebarMenu(
              menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart")),
              menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("dollar")),
              menuItem("Item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("credit-card")),
              menuItem("Item 4", tabName = "t_item4", icon = icon("share-alt"))
            )
          )
        }
      })
```

Remove also the `dashboardBody` from the "body" render function:

```
output$body <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      mainpage
    }
    else {
      login
    }
  })
```

It should fix the problem.

By the way, is it safe to use this kind of login authentication?

Comment: ditto on the 'is it safe to use this kind of login authentication' question. I implemented something similar, but with salt and pepper for the user's password, though I'm not sure if this could be easily hacked. There's also no saved login state, so if the user refreshes the screen, they'll need to log in again.

Comment: FYI, its not safe to use this sort of thing. I would suggest adding PAM onto your shiny server

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems that PAM only works with the Pro version of Shiny. There is any other safe alternative compatible withe free version of Shiny?